# Resolving error while installing devstack train on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, openstack, devstack

I am trying to install `devstack` **train** on `ubuntu` and get the following error:

> ContextualVersionConflict: (glance-store 0.28.1
> (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages),
> Requirement.parse('glance-store>=1.0.0'), set(['glance'])) You are
> using pip version 9.0.3, however version 21.2.4 is available. You
> should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I did try upgrading `pip` using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

But when I ran `./stack.sh` again, I face the same issue.

Can you please let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the really true `error` reason is: `Requirement.parse('glance-store>=1.0.0')`,

Try this:

```
sudo pip install glance-store==1.0.0
```

the version `1.0.0` should replace by what you need.